# ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied).. for Step Functions' Lambdas to get_object, despite relevant permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

As part of an AWS Step Function flow, being run in batches of 20 or more, I have a Lambda (A) that successfully saves a file to s3, then another Lambda (B) that downloads it with boto3 get_object for further processing. The strange thing is; that some of step function iterations fail because the second Lambda (B) runs into a `ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied)`, whereas some iterations of the Step function succeed with no errors.

According to AWS; a file saved to s3 should be available immediatly upon saving.

Policy for both Lambdas is this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Abort*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::filesbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::filesbucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to add a boto3 `get_waiter('object_exists')` in Lambda (B) but that didn't help and some Step Function iterations failed with `Waiter ObjectExists failed: An error occurred (403): Forbidden`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing the upload and download in the same Step Functions, trigger the Step function using the S3 Event for create. That ways you dont have to worry about the S3 object being ready.

Comment: Thanks, that would probably be a working solution, although I would prefer to stick to this original architecture, and I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end which worked, was adding retries to the invocation of the second Lambda (B);

Using the CDK;

```
.add_retry(
        errors=["ClientError"],
        interval=Duration.seconds(4),
        max_attempts=12,
        backoff_rate=1.5,
    )
```

Or in the State Machine definition;

```
   "Retry": [
    ........
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "ClientError"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 4,
      "MaxAttempts": 12,
      "BackoffRate": 1.5
    }
  ]
```

It seems like AWS can take a few seconds for objects saved to S3 to be available for download by boto3.